# Blank html opening form inside iframe in bootstrap modal

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I have a two steps form presented inside an iframe that is inside a bootstrap modal. When user submits the form its is redirected to second step. Nothing unsual.

The problem is: sometimes, after user submits the form in first step the iframe gets completely blank (see following video).

1. The frequency this problem happens is very random. Sometimes I try 10/20 times and everythings works fine. Sometimes I try 3 times and every try results in a blank iframe in second step.
2. If I do any action that draws something in the browser canvas or force canvas redraw, the iframe gets visible instantly (example: resizing window or inspecting iframe html using chrome developer tools).
3. Even iframe is blank, the input elements remains interactable.
4. This problem is happening in Google Chrome.
5. In the following video for example, problem happens the third time I get second step, and the iframe is correctly displayed only after I click button "Select an element in the page..." from chrome developer tools.

[image: Text]

Form remains interactable yet it is not visible
[image: Text]

I tried the following to "force" iframe redraw, but with no success:

1. Call window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); after iframe gets loaded.
2. Append some text to iframe contents() after iframe gets loaded.
3. Change iframe z-index after iframe gets loaded.
4. Change iframe scrollTop after iframe gets loaded.
5. Change iframe height after iframe gets loaded.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

**EDIT 1**

I realized that problem happens when I directly open the second step form in iframe/modal too. In another words, the problem has no connection with form submiting from step 1 to 2.

The problem seems to be related with presence of scripts in the opened page. In my case form has some widgets, like jquery autocomplete. The more widgets I add to form (more complex form) the more frequently problem happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem calling the following method in the iframe load event:

```
function forceRedraw(element){

    if (!element) { return; }

    var n = document.createTextNode(' ');
    var disp = element.style.display;  // don't worry about previous display style

    element.appendChild(n);
    element.style.display = 'none';

    setTimeout(function(){
        element.style.display = disp;
        n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
    },20); // you can play with this timeout to make it as short as possible
}
```

Listening event and calling method:

```
$iframe.on('load', function() {          
        if ($iframe.attr('src') != 'about:blank') {
            setTimeout(function(){             
                forceRedraw($iframe[0]);
            }, 100);
        }
    });
```